# SQL Server Merge statement compatibility issue

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have used the `Merge` statement in my stored procedure and it's work fine on the development server, but when I am updating this to one of the my clients system its giving me the following error.

> Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: And what's unclear about that message?

Comment: Which version of SQL server you have at the client end?

Comment: Have your client check and/or correct the compatibility level on their server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database

Comment: >>>compatibility level on their server<<< server has a version, not compatibility_level, the last is database property and can be set individually on every database induvidually except for system databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is server error, SSMS has nothing to do with it. Please update your question with the results of

```
select @@version;

select compatibility_level
from sys.databases
where name = 'yourDB'
```

If your server version is <= 2005 there is nothing you can do about it, but it seems that your server version is higher, only db compatibility level is low (you need at least 100)

Answer (score 5):

In this case (when compatibility level of DB is < 100) you may try use semicolon before and in the end of MERGE like this:

```sql
;MERGE t1
USING t2
ON ...
INSERT (...)
VALUES (...);
```

This may help because in lower compatibility level SQLServer needs semicolon in end of  statement before MERGE.